# Web components render its code when I append them from a father to other

Tags: javascript, web-component, dom-manipulation

I have a system that create and order web components in a list like duolingo. First I create append the components to a general container and later I separate them into groups of 2 and 3 into divs. But when I append the components from the general container to the divs, the code get duplicated into the shadow-root.

```
function fetchPosts() {
const URL = `${API_URL}posts/`;
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.classList = 'courses-list';

container.setAttribute('id','new-container')
fetch(URL, {method:"GET", headers: {Authorization: `Token ${AUTH_TOKEN()}`}})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    })
    .then(data => {
        data.forEach(element => {
            const component = document.createElement('course-item');
            component.setAttribute('class', 'course-container')
            //set more attributes
            container.append(component)
        });
        document.querySelector('.main-content').append(container);
        orderPosts();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

function orderPosts() {
    const newContainer = document.getElementById('new-container');
    let item = document.querySelectorAll('course-item');
    let nodos = [];
    let counter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    counter++;
    if(counter === 2) {

        let nodo = document.createElement('div');
        nodo.append(item[i-1], item[i])
        nodos.push(nodo);
        
    } else if(counter === 5) {

        let nodo = document.createElement('div');
        nodo.append(item[i-2], item[i-1], item[i])
        nodos.push(nodo)
        counter = 0;

   }
}
newContainer.append(...nodos);
    }
```

using debubger I saw effectively **the web component calls connectedCallback() two times**, so the template get render two times into the web component

The component

```
class courseItem extends HTMLElement {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
}

static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['emoji', 'coursetitle', 'date', 'difficulty', 'url']
}

attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (attr === 'emoji') {
        this.emoji = newVal;
    }
    //etc..
}

getTemplate() {
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `
    /*template HTML*/
    ${this.getStyle()}
    `
    return template;
}

getStyle() {
    return `
        <style>
       /*styles*/
        </style>
    `
}

render() {
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.getTemplate().content.cloneNode(true))
}

connectedCallback() {
    this.render();
    debugger
}

DisconnectedCallback(){
    this.shadowRoot.removeChild(this.getTemplate());
}
```

}

customElements.define('course-item', courseItem);

I tried to remove the child when disconnectedCallback() but it didn't work

Comment: Please post code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: I think I solved it! I added a boolean "isRendered" into the web component constructor, and when the component was rendered the value turned true. In that way, I got the component get render only one time

Comment: Yes, ``connectedCallback`` is called for every insert into the DOM **and for every move** in the DOM (your sort does that)